# Tool to apply only some changes in Git

Tags: git, pycharm

Say I have two files "version 1.py" and "version 3.py". I want to have a version in between "version 2.py" because for example, I made two changes (e.g. feature A and bugfix 1) and I don't want to commit both changes simultaneously, as that isn't considered good practice. What I did is, I had the diff open on one side of the screen and manually copied the changes I want into the Pycharm-IDE. So what is the workflow in this case? There should be a tool to do that, shouldn't it? I didn't found one. I would take any tool I find and is advanced enough, I would however prefer a way to do that in Pycharm or Git. I found emacs with patch files, however emacs doesn't take the original file so it don't know when you're trying to change the source file. That resulted in me corrupting the patch and then the patch not being accepted by git.

Comment: `git add -p` is designed for this case. I don't like it much myself, but it does work. Note that Git doesn't use your *working tree* file when committing, but rather the *index* copy of the file; `git add -p` compares index and working tree copy, makes a diff from the comparison, and lets you selectively add pieces of the diff *to* the index copy.

Comment: Are you saying you have two different files? Or that you made two changes to the same file and you'd like to separate them into two commits? If it's the second, `git add -p`.

Comment: Thank you both, indeed `git add -p` is working and indeed it's ugly. I tried a test repro as well as the two files I had from my real problem. It works however every second hunk had to be edited and I still get headaches from the numbers I have to fill in above (I even tried to leave them as they are Git didn't allowed me to do so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made multiple changes to a file and you want to separate them into multiple commits, use `git add -p`. "p" for "patch". This will walk you through your changes one-by-one and ask if you want to stage them. Stage the ones you want.

`git diff` will show you your remaining unstaged changes.

`git diff --staged` will show you the changes you've staged.

If you want to test just your staged changes you can [stash your unstaged changes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) and retrieve them later.

Once you're sure of what you've staged, commit it. `git commit`, not `git commit -a`.

---

You can use PyCharm to do all  of this. You can [Commit part of a file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/commit-and-push-changes.html#partial_commit), equivalent to `git commit -p`. But if you do that you can't test what you're committing.

For full flexibility, see ["Use the Git staging area to commit changes"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/commit-and-push-changes.html#use-git-staging-area-to-commit-changes) on how to enable the staging area in PyCharm and how to use their commit tool to stage partial changes. Equivalent to `git add -p`.

[image]

And you can use PyCharm to stage your unstaged changes. PyCharm calls this "shelving". See [Use Git to work on several features simultaneously](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/work-on-several-features-simultaneously.html).

---

This works because in Git you build up what you want to commit in the "staging area". This is what `git add` does, it copies files to the staging area. When you `git commit` you commit what is in the staging area, not what is on disk.

For most tasks you can just `git add .` to copy everything to the staging area, or `git commit -a` to copy everything and commit. But you can also select what you copy. You can only stage certain files with `git add <filename>`. And you can only stage certain changes with `git add -p`.

Comment: Thanks, the `git add -p` is somewhat helpful. I wait for other answers as I hope, there will be a better tool. I have problems with the numbers I have to correct if I edit a hunk.

Comment: @user3289974 There might be an IDE which does the same thing, but more conveniently. Be sure to use split to break up large patches. And what to you mean by "numbers you have to correct"? If you mean the line numbers in the diff header, a good editor should do that for you.

Comment: I'll try the split. For the IDE, yeah that's something I'm searching for. For the good editor, you get head aches when you have to count the number of lines your own, I would like to automate that

Comment: @user3289974 PyCharm can do it. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/commit-and-push-changes.html#use-git-staging-area-to-commit-changes

Comment: @user3289974 I've updated the answer with the related PyCharm tools.

Comment: Yeah, the link you gave helped. I'm not happy with the internal diff algorithm, but I guess this is time for another question / some research / support of PyCharm

Comment: @user3289974 You can change the diff algorithm, and even use a different diff program entirely. See [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: I'm happy with the git diff algorithm, but not with the PyCharm diff algorithm. You can also change in Pycharm but I need a GUI-Tool so I can't use Git directly unfortunately.

Comment: @user3289974 See `git-difftool` for how to choose which visual diff tool Git uses.

Comment: hey thanks, which difftool do you suggest for python?

Comment: @GuiTaek PyCharm would be my recommendation, but I don't use Python nor difftools much. What do you find lacking in PyCharm?

Comment: sometimes when I make a diff, it doesn't really "calculate" the diff but generate a big hunk with a lot of - lines and + lines, for the same file, git diff did better